# Simple ajax asp.net calendar extender not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar, calendarextender

I've made a new project with one page and a reference to `AjaxControlToolkit.dll`

The calendar extender below doesn't work, what have I done wrong?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" CssClass="ClassName" Format="MMMM d, yyyy" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using the ajaxtoolkit ScriptManager instead of the asp one..everything else looks fine

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" > </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is correct; however, it didn't work for me.  I tried instead to drag the ToolkitScriptManager into my form, and it was rendered as

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>"<
```

.  It worked for me then.  Note that it was "asp.ToolkitScriptManager", not "ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager".  Perhaps this is a change in the version of the Ajax Control Toolkit I am using?

Answer (score 5):

No, Its what ever you set the tagPrefix as, It could be cc1 or asp or ajaxToolkit

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

regarding Ajax Control Toolkit 7.1213.0

Since you are using the ajax control toolkit you will need to use **ToolScriptManager** instead of just **ScriptManager**.

Drag and drop **ToolScriptManager** or just type

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

if not working put this in the begining of web page.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

You can use **CalendarExtender** right after targeted textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate1" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDate1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDate1">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

If these are not working you should edit your **Web.config** file and add necessary configurations. Add configurations to ajax controls which will need you to refer another tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

```
<httpHandlers>
                <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*"/>
                <add path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
                <add path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
                <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
                <add path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" verb="GET" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
                <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
            </httpHandlers>
    <system.web></system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is already answered, but just to let the developers facing this problem **NOW** , talking about the version [Update October 2015:](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) which is **now** maintained by [DevExpress](https://go.devexpress.com/AjaxControlToolkit_CodePlex_DevExpressHome.aspx)

I upgraded my **VS 2013 Web Forms** application project to ajax via **Nuget** 
&
I faced the same problem, **Calender control not working**, having all the code perfect

So the solution that worked for me was :

**1.** I did this:

[image]

**2.** I installed it via this **New** installer

**3.** I created a **New** project in my VS 2013

**4.** Moved my **existing code** to this project and

### it worked !!

plus, 
thers is no `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager` now , you have to Use the standard **ScriptManager** now

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sigh... I know this is question was dated, but in case others arrive and these solutions don't solve the problem then here is something to check. We have a legacy web forms app that I spent most of the morning troubleshooting because the calendar extender controls just stopped working on a specific page.  There were no patches or service packs that had been run on server/local dev pc and no Ajax assembly version change and no recent change to the page.

It turns out that a register startup script in page load was referring to a JavaScript function that no longer existed in the external js file hence a JavaScript Error on page load stopped the ajax control initialization/functionality.  So check your developer tools (Chrome seems the best) for JavaScript errors that may stop other JavaScript initialization scripts from running for calendar extender and similar.